# Template checkbox checked property is getting false in Gridview for delete operation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have used template CheckBox in gridview for multiple rows deletion, when I select multiple rows by selecting the CheckBox and perform the delete operation it seems to be selected CheckBox is not returning true on the code below.

protected void Button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            LinkButton ch = new LinkButton();
            ch = (LinkButton)row.FindControl("l1");
            id = Convert.ToInt16(ch.CommandArgument);
            CheckBox chs = new CheckBox();
            chs = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("c1"));

            if (chs.Checked == true)
            {
                DeleteSelected(id);
            }
        }
    }

private void DeleteSelected(short id)
{
    var ch = from a in empd.Employees where (a.ID == id) select a;
    empd.Employees.DeleteAllOnSubmit(ch);
    empd.SubmitChanges();
    display_emp();
}
```

Could someone please assist me why `CheckBox` is not returning true value in calling function.

Well now I have fixed the connection everything, please just refresh the database.Please get the web application in the below link.

http://www.ziddu.com/download/20716096/WebApplication.zip.html
Please help me on why selected checkbox are not returning true in the code.

Comment: make sure you don't reset the gridview before checking what i selected..

Comment: I didn’t find anything to upload the code, so here is a link for the sample web application below.
http://www.ziddu.com/download/20715484/WebApplication.zip.html

Comment: I have attached the sample web application in with above link, anyone please help me out of this.

Comment: It doesn't work the way you upload 500kB of code and ask for fix.

Comment: It will work not because you need to set the connectionstring(DemosConnectionString1) in web.config file, database is there in App_data folder so you can establish the connection and set it into web.config file.

Comment: Hi Michal

Please help me I think you know where is the problem. If you debug the code then you can see the template(Linkbutton) is returning the value but not the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

**Details:** Add if(IsPostback) at the start otherwise it just resets your grid controls. Example below

**Solution:**

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
 {
     empd = new Employee_DetailsDataContext();
     empd.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DemosConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

     display_emp();
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much it's worked for me.

But now I am facing one more problem why retrieval of a querry (var ch = from a in empd.Employees where (a.ID == Convert.ToInt16(id)) select a) giving an exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Could you please resolve this as well for me?

Comment: I have now resolved this problem as well. I have just added two lines of code as follows:

empd = new Employee_DetailsDataContext();
            empd.Connection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DemosConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;

But I am not understanding why I need to recreate the object of datacontext when I have already created in IsPostback event. IS there any way to simplyfy this.